# How do I modify a core CiviCRM file (to change a search order)?

Tags: api, extension, hooks, developer, mysql

Looks like one of core CiviCRM files (namely part of mySQL query at CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php) has to be changed in order to achieve "[Search results sort by Last Name](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7720/search-result-sort-by-last-name)". What would be the best (I mean, most proper) way in CiviCRM to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already here. According to tiny mention at the bottom of http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Directories page, it is possible (and, more important, it works!) to copy modofyed core files to  **Custom PHP Path Directory** (at civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1) , preserving original files/folders structure, so next time CiviCRM gets security updates, changes should be kept (unless original file / function major changes).